# JSF PrimeFaces / Ajax rendering to Datable fails to add items to the list

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean, session-scope

I am trying to user a form in 'panelGrid' to render values in a `dataTable` using `<f:ajax>`. However, when submitting using the `<h:commandButton>` the values sent are not displayed in the `dataTable`. I am not getting a stack or any console errors in the browsers.

This is the my xhtml (Simplified):

Product Catalog:

```
    <p:tabView id="tabView" style="width: 65%" >
            <p:tab id="books" title="Books">
                <p:dataGrid var="book" value="#{saleBean.productList}" columns="3"
                            rows="9" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} 
                            {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} 
                            {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="3,6,9">
                    <h:form id="product" >
                    <p:panel header="#{book.name}" style="text-align: center">


                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 65%">

                                <!-- Add Book Images here -->
                                <h:outputText value="#{book.price}"/>

                                <h:outputLabel value="Dct (in dollars): " />
                                <h:inputText id="discount" value="#{saleBean.item.unit_discount}" style="width: 50%" />

                                <p:commandButton value="Add to Cart" update=":dataTableForm:sc" 
                                                 action="#{saleBean.doAddItem}"/>


                            </h:panelGrid>


                    </p:panel>
                    </h:form>          
                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="arts" title="Art / Various">
                <!-- Art Products to be added here -->
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="other" title="Other">
                <!-- Various Products to be Added here -->
            </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>


    <hr/>        
    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
    <hr/>

    <h:form id="dataTableForm">
    <p:dataTable id="sc" value="#{saleBean.sd}" var="item" style="width: 60%">

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Product"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.product_fk}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Quantity"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.quantity}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Unit Price"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.unit_Cost}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Unit Discount"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.unit_discount}"/>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

This the bean (Simplified):

```
   public String doAddItem()
    {
        item.setUnit_Cost(product.getPrice());        
        item.setProduct_fk(product);
        item.setQuantity(1);
        sd.add(item); 

        return "productCatalog";
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to move your action from h:commandButton to listener in f:ajax ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie thank you very much. I have implemented the suggested changes, but I get `The class 'com.lv.Controllers.SaleBean' does not have the property 'doAddItem'.` I do have the `doAddItem`. Are they any other suggestions you may have? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to change ActionEvent for AjaxBehaviorEvent.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie thanks. I have been trying to use the AjaxBehaviorEvent, but still I get the `The class 'com.lv.Controllers.SaleBean' does not have the property 'doAddItem'`.

Answer (score 1):

According to PrimeFaces documentation :

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandButton.html

Your `actionListener="#{saleBean.doAddItem}"` must use a function corresponding to that :

```
public void doAddItem(ActionListener event)
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

To use action here is an example :

```
action="#{saleBean.doAddItem}"

public String doAddItem(void)
{

    item.setUnit_Cost(product.getPrice());        
    item.setProduct_fk(product);
    item.setQuantity(1);
    sd.add(item); 

    return "productCatalog";
}
```

Comment: Alexandre thanks again. I have used the ActionListener suggestion but still, after pressing the button nothing happens. I have updated my code above reflecting the changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the second example above. Wasn't knowing that you needed action!

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, I have updated the code using action. However, still the table is not being updated with the values after pressing the button. I wasn't able to use the `(void)` because it requires to use a `<identifier>` and return an exception. So, for the `doAddItem` method I used like you suggested but without the `(void)`. Is there any other code that I provide that could help you  get a better view of the situation?

Comment: Well if you want to refresh the table, the first example is ok, use actionListener, not action. Also you need to put your bean ViewScoped or SessionScoped.

Comment: Alexandre, sorry I said 'refresh', what I meant was the functionality of `action`. My `SaleBean` is annotated with `sessionScoped`, could it be a problem/limitation of the `tabView` or `panelGrid`? I am a bit confused because I am new to JSF and PrimeFaces and I have tried different things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: action is used to go to another view (page). To refresh a table you can use actionListener, this will do your stuff and reload the current view. For that you need bean in ViewScoped or SessionScoped generally. Your variable sd.add(item); (sd) must be inside that bean too. If this variable is modified elsewhere, it may cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use only pf components when you can eg p:datatable. Replace the button with a p:commandButton and use process and update instead of f:ajax.

Also maybe it will by better to include the p:datatable in the form too.

Comment: Spyros, thank you very much. I have changed everything to primeFaces, however, after changing it I am facing a different issue, it is giving me a `Cannot find component with identifier "sc" referenced from "tabView:j_idt8:0:product:addToCart".` stack. The name of the table where the info should be updated is `sc`. I have updated my code in the original post to reflect the changes. Please let me know if there is anything you suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your table is not wrapped in a h:form component. Try to wrap it in the same h:form, that would be h:form id="product" . If this works and you do not want everything to be in the same form then use a another form eg h:form id="datatableForm" and refer to as render=":datatableForm:sc"

Comment: I managed to removed the  can't find component error. However, after trying your suggestion, I still don't get the button to work at all. I have updated the code above. Let me know if you have any suggestion to tackle this. Thanks in advance.